# Reference text box value in another form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I know this has probably been asked 1000 times but I can't get my head around it

I have a text box on a form called 'Settings' that stores a file path and I need to reference that file path in a form called 'Main

I know this should be simple but just cannot get it to work!

Any simple advice

Thanks

As below i need the Dim zMailbox to refer to a textbox value on a separate form (Settings)

```
Public Class Main

Dim zMailbox As String = "C:\Dropbox\User\Lynx\In\"



Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim lynxin As New IO.DirectoryInfo(zMailbox)

    lstPlanned.Items.Clear()

    For Each txtfi In lynxin.GetFiles("*.txt")

        lstPlanned.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtfi.Name)) 

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reference"? Does Main open Settings and need the value afterwards or is Settings opened along with Main and Main needs to access the current value of the TextBox?

Comment: There are many reasons why you might have problems to access the information in a variable/control. Please, post your code and provide more clear indications.

Comment: Basically the settings page is set up once during install of the program and normally would never be changed. Everytime the program would then open it would use the the defined filepath from a text box to perform the day to day functions. Whilst building the program I've hard coded the file path on the 'Main' form using Dim blah as string = c:\blah\blah. This has been set right at the top of the form however i would simply like it to reference the text box in the Dim rather than a file path. Thanks

Comment: From your original description I don't know what is what you are doing wrong (textbox not getting the value, intending to access the textbox without the required permissions, intending to access the class where the textbox is defined wrongly, etc.). Why you think that your last comment has changed this at all? Can you please follow the suggestion (post your code and explain better what you do; but from the code, not from an abstract reality point of view) such that you can get help quickly?

Comment: If you add two forms to the same project by using add->Form, you should be able to do: `Dim zMailbox As String = Settings.TextBox1.Text` (where `TextBox1` is the given textbox).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that however i get a 'The path is not of a legal form' error highlighted on this line `Dim lynxin As New IO.DirectoryInfo(zMailbox)`

Comment: In this case, it seems pretty clear that zMailbox does not contain a valid path (is perhaps the textbox.text returning a blank string? Shouldn't you check whether this is the case (the user actually inputted a valid path) before using this variable?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using something like My.Settings

To do so, you right-click on your project and then click Properties. On the left side, you have a tab called "Settings". You can create a setting there and give it a default value. Ex : MyPath.

Then on your Settings form, you set your value into My.Settings.MyPath.

```
My.Settings.MyPath = TextboxPath.Text.Trim()
```

So when you want to access it anywhere in your application after, you can just use :

```
My.Settings.MyPath
```